# How to match the exact number of digits with regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript, what I have done is the following:

`var matched = searched.match(/\d{7}/)`

It works great if `searched` is `1234567` or `XYZ1234567`. Both return `1234567`, which is good. `123` and `XYZ123` return null, which is expected.

But one condition fails when `searched` is `12345678` or `XYZ12345678`. I would like both to return null because I look for an exact 7 digit match. They both return `2345678` instead.

`/\d{7}$/` does not work either.

Can someone please advise?

Thank you

Comment: Does forcing the start of the string and end of the string work? `/^(\d{7})$/`

Comment: You need a regex that is 7 consecutive digits bounded by either start/end of string or by non-digits.

Answer (score 4):

`(?:\D|^)`: begins with non-digit

`(?:\D|$)`: ends with non-digit

```
var matched = searched.match(/(?:\D|^)(\d{7})(?:\D|$)/);
if (matched) { 
  matched = matched[1]; 
}
```

Comment: You can use \D instead of [^\d] and this also matches `c1234567` in `abc1234567`.

Comment: thanks. i didn't know how javascript non-capture group really behaved

Comment: You could shorten this to `var [, matched] = searched.match(regex) || []` although I'd fully understand if you leave it as is. The one liner is a bit cryptic.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a lookaround based regex. Lookbehind adoption in browsers is gaining momentum, [Firefox supports lookbehinds in regexps](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/78) since June 30, 2020.

Use

```
 /(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)/
```

Or, to find all occurrences,

```
/(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QRlOcC/1)

The `(?<!\d)` negative lookbehind matches any position not immediately preceded with a digit, `\d{7}` matches seven digits and `(?!\d)` negative lookahead requires no digit immediately on the right.

```js
const values = ['1234567A', 'XYZ1234567A', '12345678', 'XYZ12345678'];
const regex = /(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)/g;
for (let val of values) {
  console.log(val, '\nMatch found:',
       /(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)/.test(val), '\nMatch value: ',
       Array.from(val.matchAll(regex), m => m[0])
  )
}
```

Output:

```
1234567A 
Match found: true 
Match value:  [
  "1234567"
]
XYZ1234567A 
Match found: true 
Match value:  [
  "1234567"
]
12345678 
Match found: false 
Match value:  []
XYZ12345678 
Match found: false 
Match value:  []
```